# Handlebars dynamic table

Tags: javascript, templates, handlebars.js

I am trying to create a dynamic table using Handlebars. What I want is to iterate through an object where I don't know what the property names are. I found one way of doing it, where I push all the data into a new object with a new property name.

```
$.each(data[i], function(key, value) {
  output.tableContent.push({
   contentName: value
  });
 });
}
```

The problem in doing this is that it doesn't separate the objects so when I put it into the table I just get one long row in my table.

The handlebars template I use looks like this:

```
{{#each tableContent}}
 <tr>
  <td>{{contentName}}</td>
 </tr>
{{/each}}
```

I know I could access it by doing `{{contentName.propertyname}}`, but as stated above, the property names are unknown (based on userinput).
I also tried `{{this}}` instead of  `{{contentName}}`, but this just returns `Object object`

Comment: Could you post the sample data which you need to iterate ?

Comment: It is unclear what your expected result is.